# Can we put more than 2 text or images in 'Flip-animation' or 'Flip-motion', if yes,then how?

Tags: html, css

Can we put more than 2 text or images in 'Flip-animation' or 'Flip-motion', if yes,then how?

I googled it, but couldn't find any satisfying answer. I searched this here too,but no question matched my requirements.
I require the text flip-animation for at least 3 text.
This is the CSS:

```css
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.6s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.6s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.front {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  z-index: 2;
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color:#5FBA7D;
}

.front .name {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  color: #f8f8f8;
  font-family: Courier;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 117px;
  background-color: green;
}

.back-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #00304a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <div>
        <p class="back-title">Front</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div>
        <p class="back-title">Back</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its HTML written above:

Comment: Flip has only two possibilities, for more than that you need to think of different design/animation.

Comment: You can try with different flip directions for different data.

Comment: Can you give me a link.

Comment: Well I don't have the working demo, but you can try something like this: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

This provides you all possible flips. so you can decide what data to show depending upon the flip.

Comment: Arpit, the above example(my code) is from that site only... but still thanks